# Difficulties subsetting dataframe by date in R

Tags: r

I've looked at a bunch of other stackoverflow threads and I can't seem to get any of their solutions to work for me. Here is what my file looks like

```
date_time                   user    desk
8/26/2014  8:13:00 AM       1       main
```

to

```
date_time                   user    desk
8/27/2014  10:16:00 AM      5       main
```

`date_time` is considered a factor, but I use lubridate like so:

```
datetime <- desktracker$date_time
mydate <- mdy_hms(as.character(datetime))
```

To get `date_time` as a date. I want to subset the data frame by day in `date_time`. I've tried the following:

```
desktracker$date_time2 <- as.Date(as.character(desktracker$date_time), "%d-%m-%y")
WeekOf826 <- subset(desktracker, date_time2 > as.Date("2014-8-26"))
```

And it produces an empty variable. I've also tried substituting the - for / but that also does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you don't convert the datetime class to `as.POSIXct`?

Comment: After I use lubridate's mdy_hms() on the date_time, class(mydate) reveals that it becomes POSIXct.

Comment: Comparing Dates to datetimes will generally fail. They have two different underlying numeric representations. There is an as.character method for datetimes but the format you have chosen would be wrong,, but why do that at all? There is an as.Date method for POSIXt objects.